# PHP anonymous function without this inside

Tags: php, this, anonymous-function

how to declare a function inside a class without this?

```
<?php

class modul {

    var $i=1;
    var $j=1;

    public function init(){
        $test1 = function($vRecord){
            return 'zwrot';
        };
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($test1);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

}

$modul = new modul();
$modul->init();
```

my result when i print:

```
Closure Object
(
    [this] => modul Object
        (
            [i] => 1
            [j] => 1
        )

    [parameter] => Array
        (
            [$vRecord] => 
        )

)
```

how to pass function without key: 'this'? i want a pure function in print_r and resoult like this:

code:

```
<?php
$test2 = function($vRecord){
    return 'zwrot';
};
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($test2);
echo "</pre>";
```

result when i print:

```
Closure Object
(
    [parameter] => Array
        (
            [$vRecord] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: The `this` in this case is part of the class, not the function

Comment: yes i know, but it is possible to declare pure anonymous function inside object?

Comment: If your `init` function is static, then there's no `$this`. Not clear from your question whether that's a usable option.

Comment: I love this type of questions! Check out [this link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static), I think it's what you're looking for

Comment: yes! super thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a [Static anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static):

```
    $test1 = static function($vRecord){
        return 'zwrot';
    };
```